# resolving a support ticket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i am trying to create a support system. In which user can raise ticket and our support team will resolve it and user can see our reply. Here point to be noted is i don't want to use any kind of email system. How do i resolve this any help would be thankful.

My table structure below:here ticket number is unique and generate once for every ticket.

```
 +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | company_id        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | subject           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | description       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_by        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_date      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | assigned_to       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | status_id         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | completed_date    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | ticket_number     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | deleted           | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
```

Comment: Thats an incredibly vauge and open question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a solution for support ticket. I used separate namespace for admin and seperate table for support ticket, now a use can generate ticket and admin is default receiver for that ticket. When admin reply any ticket the user who created the ticket will be the receiver.